# Regex remove first section and optional last section

Tags: regex

I need to use a regular expression to match `ci-` which will always be there, but then match the optional `-l`, `-s`, `-r`, so then I can extract the middle part, but as you can see some of the below examples have got dashes separating other words, which I don't want to remove.

```
ci-star-l
ci-pound-sign
ci-pound-sign-r
```

The above would become:

```
star
pound-sign
pound-sign
```

This is my attempt, however it is wrong:

```
(ci-).*(-.)
```

Comment: Replace with `^ci-|-[lsr]$`? See https://regex101.com/r/3quW1x/1

Comment: That appears to work spot on, thanks! I can never get my head around regular expressions!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest replacing the matches of

```
^ci-|-[lsr]$
```

with an empty string. Note the regex replace method/function must support multiple replacements.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3quW1x/1).

**Details**

- `^ci-` - `ci-` at the start
- `|` - or
- `-[lsr]$` - `-` and `l` / `s` / `r` at the end of the string.

If you want to use your initial approach you may consider

```
^ci-(.*?)(?:-[lsr])?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NwhPC9/2). Here, `(.*?)` grabs any 0+ chars but as few as possible into Group 1 and `(?:-[lsr])?$` matches an optional `-l`, `-r`, `-s` at the end of the string. The `*?` non-greedy quantifier and the `$` anchor are crucial for this regex to work. Replacement must be done with the backreference to Group 1 (usually, `$1` or `\1`).

Answer (score 2):

`(...)` is a matching group, from which you can get the context later.

`$` is the end of the string.

Therefore, I would use `ci-(.*?)(?:-\w)?$` and your result is then the first matching group.

Comment: yes, you're right. I overlooked the "optional". `ci-(.*)(?:-\w)?$`? with an optional non-capturing group `(?:...)`